# 0xc000000f error when trying to boot PC

Tags: hard-drive, boot

I have a PC which I'm trying to boot. I keep getting the following error:

```
        Windows failed to start. A recent software or hardware change might be the cause. To fix the problem:
     1. Insert your windows installation disc and restart your computer.
     2. choose your language settings, and then click "Next."
     3. Click "Repair your computer"
If you do not have this disc, contact your system administrator or computer manufacturer for assistance.

Status: 0xc000000f
Info: The boot selection failed because a required device is inaccessible.
```

Searching through Google and SuperUser, I've found several solutions which I've tried:

1. I've changed the PATA cable for it has been suggested that the cable can be faulty.
2. I have inserted 4 different windows discs, the PC won't even boot to repair the system.
3. I have tried 3 different CD drives for it has been also suggested that the drive can be faulty.
4. I've tried 4 different HDD hard drives. Same issue.
5. In the BIOS options, I've tried different boot sequences.
6. I've tried changing the connection arrangement by which the CD drive and the hard drive are connected.

All these attempts have failed. Same error, same situation. Am I missing something here? Again, I would boot from CD but it doesn't seem to see the CD all together.

Comment: Typically .....  This issue occurs when one of following conditions is true: The Boot Configuration Data (BCD) is corrupted. The reference to DEVICE and OSDEVICE on the boot configuration data is missing or unknown. The binary displayed on the screenshot (other than winload.exe or \boot\BCD) is missing from the operating system disk.    .....  If no hard drive will boot, is there a hardware error.  Run the manufacturer's Hardware Diagnostic App.

Comment: @John Thank you for you answer, the PC I'm trying to boot is kinda old with no obvious information about the manufacturer. Is there like a generic third party program I can use?

Comment: See if you can find a diagnostic app tor your brand of motherboard.   That is what I would try.

Comment: It appears you have two concurrent issues: HDD isn't needed to boot CD, so CD not booting is issue2. Please clarify HOW you attempted to boot CD (boot order or pressing key for boot menu), what error you got, how the CD drive is connected to the PC (ex: SATA or IDE, which port on motherboard, which part of cable)

Comment: AFTER you successfully boot up Windows CD tell us if the HDD is detected inside Windows installer. If its not maybe a SATA/RAID/AHCI setting was toggled in the BIOS

Answer (score 0):

Since you state this is an old machine, but you *can* get into BIOS, try booting from a USB flash drive with "live" Linux (i.e., not just installation media, but actually bootable).

- If you can boot and run Linux from the USB itself, you know the PC is working, though there are likely issues with the HDD. You can keep working from the USB drive without installing Linux, if you wish.
- However, if you ,ike Linux, you can also *install* Linux on the HDD, *if* the HDD is not damaged.

An easy Linux distro to test is Ubuntu. [To make a live Ubuntu USB drive](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/try-ubuntu-before-you-install#1-getting-started), you'll need a USB flash drive, the Ubuntu ISO (I'd recommend version [20.04 LTS](https://www.releases.ubuntu.com/focal/ubuntu-20.04.5-desktop-amd64.iso) or 22.04) and [Rufus](https://rufus.ie/en/) to create a bootable USB drive from that ISO.

**N.B.:** You need to know if your PC is quite old, using a 32-bit OS, or the newer 64-bit OS. Look up the model number online. Older machines can still use [Lubuntu 18.04](https://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/18.04/release/lubuntu-18.04.5-desktop-i386.iso), but there will be no upgrades from that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer but linux is not an option since the person working on the PC is not tech savvy. But I will try your solution to check if the PC is working

Answer (score 0):

Error code 0xc000000f during the boot means that the BCD file was not found.

Your disk has experienced a catastrophic error, and you should check
whether it is still usable, or if it needs to be replaced.

You need to boot a Linux Live USB to examine the SMART attributes
of the disk (if it's not too old to have SMART), using the command:

```
sudo smartctl -a /dev/sda
```

This command produces a lot of output, but you're looking only for
The SMART section which looks like:

```
SMART Attributes Data Structure revision number: 16
Vendor Specific SMART Attributes with Thresholds:
ID# ATTRIBUTE_NAME          FLAG     VALUE WORST THRESH TYPE      UPDATED  WHEN_FAILED RAW_VALUE
  1 Raw_Read_Error_Rate     0x002f   200   200   051    Pre-fail  Always       -       0
```

You could copy this information into your post for us.

Even if the disk is too old to support SMART, you can examine it,
to see if the Windows partition is still there and looks intact.

If you can't see the partition, then the disk is probably unusable.

If you can see the disk and it looks OK, re-install Windows, using
a boot media of the same type and level as the installed Windows.
It should detect the Windows partition and repair the boot.

Comment: I was thinking along your lines initially but the author tried 4 different drives

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution. I've already tried 4 different HDD drives. Same error

Comment: In that case, it might be hardware. I suggest to run whatever hardware tests are available in the BIOS. Run also [MemTest86](https://www.memtest86.com/) for many hours or over-night.